# Integral of the conjugate of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be analytic on some domain containing the closed unit disk $|z|\leq1$. Show that
$$\int_{|z|=1}\overline{f(z)}dz=2\pi i\overline{f'(0)}$$

A hint would be nice. I have tried a few directions with little success.

Comment: Power series expansion.

Comment: thanks I'll give it a shot

Comment: right but $f$ being analytic does not imply $\bar{f}$ is.

Comment: No, but $\overline{\sum c_n z^n}$ should not be where you stop.

Comment: right I was responding to another comment that disappeared

Comment: I see. Did that one expect the integral to be $0$?

Comment: Exactly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an approach. We write the integral as

> $$ I = \int_{|z|=1}\overline{f(z)}dz = \overline{ \int_{|z|=1}{f(z)}d\bar{z} }. $$

Since $z\bar{z} =1$ then

> $$ \bar{z} = \frac{1}{z} \implies d\bar{z}=-\frac{dz}{z^2}. $$

So we have

> $$ \int_{|z|=1}{f(z)}d\bar{z} = -\int_{|z|=1}{f(z)}\frac{d{z}}{z^2}=-2\pi i f'(0) $$

by [Cauchy integral formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) or the residue theorem. Finally we get the desired result

> $$ I = -\overline{2\pi if'(0)} =2\pi i \overline{f'(0)}. $$

Comment: Thanks the $z\bar{z}=1$ is where the unit disk park comes in... nice.

Comment: @coffeebelly:You are welcome. Yes, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/852547/help-with-equality-of-complex-integrals/852604#852604).

Comment: these two examples cleared up a lot of confusion about taking the conjugate of a complex integral. I was always doing it by scratch $(u-iv)(dx+idy)$ to convince myself.

Comment: @coffeebelly: At the beginning you need to work problems out from scratch to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Taylor expansion of $f(z)$ to evaluate. Note
$$ f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}z^n $$
and
$$ \int_{|z|=1}\bar{z}^ndz=i\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i(1-n)\theta}d\theta=\left\{\begin{array}{l}2\pi i, \text{ if }n=1\\ 0, \text{ else}\end{array}\right. $$
So
$$ \int_{|z|=1}\overline{f(z)}dz=\int_{|z|=1}\sum_{n=0}\frac{\overline{f^{(n)}(0)}}{n!}\bar{z}^ndz=2\pi i\overline{f'(0)}. $$