# Cauchy's Integral parametric conjugate

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

By considering the conjugate of its parametric form, evaluate $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma(0;1)}\frac{\overline{f(z)}}{z-a}dz$$ when $|a|<1$ and $|a|>1$, where $f$ is holomorphic in in the disk $(0;R),  R>1$.

Typically when doing these kinds of integration and parametrization, $|z|=n$ is given, but it's different in this case (or is it not?). Can someone help me out?

Comment: What is $\gamma(0;1)$?

Comment: @kobe its the contour integral, centered at 0 and radius 1, if that answers your question?

Comment: @science could you help me out how you obtained the answer?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864663/integral-of-the-conjugate-of-a-complex-function/864672#864672).

Comment: The answer should be $ \overline {f(0)} $.

Comment: @science Of course, you meant $\overline {f(a)}$.

Comment: The answer in the link provides a clear path to the solution here.  The result here depends on whether $|a|$ is inside the unit circle.

Comment: @RonGordon it's still not as clear to me. i can follow the derivation from the link, but here we have a different denominator... i'm still trying to figure it out, maybe you can help me out as well?

Comment: @RonGordon I would then end up with $-\int \frac{f(z)dz}{z^2(z-a)}$ where the zeroes are at $z=0, a$

Comment: Of course the answer I gave you only for one case namely $|a|<1$.

Comment: @science: that's fine, but if you want to be understood, you need to specify that up front.  None of us are mindreaders.

Comment: @RonGordon: I would've solved the problem and posted it but I was busy with something else so I did quick derivations and posted a comment. The main thing is that I referred you to the link which has the techniques. Good job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rewrite the integral as

$$\overline{\oint_{|z|=1} d\bar{z} \frac{f(z)}{\bar{z}-\bar{a}}}$$

Use the fact that $z \bar{z}=1 \implies d\bar{z} = -dz/z^2$; we get

$$-\frac1{a}\overline{\oint_{|z|=1} dz \frac{f(z)}{z \left (z-\frac1{\bar{a}}\right )}}$$

This is easily evaluated using the residue theorem.  Note that the result depends on whether $a$ is within the unit circle.  The result is

$$\frac1{i 2 \pi} \oint_{|z|=1} dz \frac{\overline{f(z)}}{z-a} = \begin{cases}\overline{f(0)} & |a| \lt 1 \\\overline{f(0)}- \overline{f \left (\frac1{\bar{a}}  \right )} & |a| \gt 1 \end{cases}$$

Comment: thanks for the clarification!